# ROR - Unable to post to Linkedin company page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linkedin-api

I'm using [linkedin-oauth2](https://github.com/emorikawa/linkedin-oauth2) gem to implement some functionalities of Linkedin in my app.

According to the documentation it says

`api.add_company_share(12345, content: "Hi")` will make a post to the company page.

It doesn't seem to work. I also tried replacing `content` part with a hash

```
{
            "visibility": {
              "code": "anyone"
            },
            "comment": "test SDK",
            "content": {
              "submitted-­url": "https://www.example.com/content.html",
              "title": "test SDK",
              "description": "test SDK",
              "submitted‐image-­url": "https://www.example.com/img.jpg"
            }
    }
```

Stil doesn't seem to work. I tried it using javascript SDK and works fine. In javascript I'm sending the data as JSON string. ( using stringify ) .

When I'm posting I'm getting following error:  `Faraday::ClientError: the server responded with status 400`

Looks like something wrong with the parameters. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Hi Sooraj Got any solution for this